# Using str_replace() and return two different versions

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a textarea where I can type in multiple domain names to check availability.
In my script below I replace space with “-“. But I also want a version of the domain name without “-”.

**Say for example that I type in:**

a good word

a nother god word

**Then I want the script to return both:**

a-good-word

a-nother-god-word

**And also:**

agoodword

anothergodword

```
$domaininput = (isset($_POST['domainname'])) ? $_POST['domainname'] : '';
$change_space = str_replace(" ","-",$domaininput);
$change_new_line = str_replace("\n",",",$change_space);
$manydomains = explode("," , $change_new_line);
foreach ($manydomains as $domain){
//some code
}
```

How can that be done in PHP?

Comment: Run your routine 2 times. Each time performing the change the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$manydomains = ... // as above...

// Get alternatives by removing dashes:
$alternatives = explode(",", str_replace("-", "", $change_new_line));

// If a domain name did not contain a dash, there will be duplicates in
// $manydomains and $alternatives.  array_unique() takes care of those.
$manydomains = array_unique(array_merge($manydomains, $alternatives));
```

Comment: It almoast work! Tought the domain is returned "a-good-word .com" and "agoodword .com". The last line is correct tough: "a-nother-god-word.com" and "anothergodword.com". Any idea why $change_new_line wont work?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$domaininput = (isset($_POST['domainname'])) ? $_POST['domainname'] : '';
$change_space = str_replace(" ","-",$domaininput);
$change_space .= str_replace(" ", "", $domaininput);
$change_new_line = str_replace("\n",",",$change_space);
$manydomains = explode("," , $change_new_line);
foreach ($manydomains as $domain){
//some code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Only returns the last line right. But it's a start!

Answer (score 0):

if you not got it to work yet here a crude function todo the job plus it will only return unique domains

```
function getDomains($domaininput){
    function domainA($domaininput){
        $return = str_replace(" ","-",$domaininput);
        return $return;
    }
    function domainB($domaininput){
        $return = str_replace("-","",$domaininput);
        return $return;
    }
    $domaininput = str_replace("\n",",",$domaininput);
    $return = domainA($domaininput)."\n";
    $return .=domainB($return);
    $return = str_replace("\n",",",$return);
    $return = trim($return,'-,');
    $return = explode(",",$return);
    $return = array_unique($return);
    return $return;
}


$manydomains = getDomains($domaininput);
```